# How to have a form control value as an object and render its label in input field?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have simple form where I have input field with autocomplete (Angular Material components). The thing is, when I select value from autocomplete box, Input fields yelds `[Object object]` as value while I would like it to be some sort of valuer related text. Is it possible out of the box or do I have to manipulate DOM element directly to achieve that?

value of that field is an `Host` object intentionally .

Form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="full-width">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Host</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="host" [matAutocomplete]="hostSuggestionsAutocomplete"
           placeholder="Host"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="delay" placeholder="Delay" type="number" min="1" max="3600"/>
    <mat-error>Delay must be between 1 and 3600 seconds</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

<mat-autocomplete #hostSuggestionsAutocomplete=matAutocomplete>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let hostSuggestion of hostSuggestions"
              [value]="hostSuggestion">{{hostSuggestion.toViewLabel()}} #{{hostSuggestion.id}}</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Host:

```
export class Host {
  id: number;
  address: String;
  label: String;
  status: HostStatus;
  lastStatusUpdate: Date;
}
Result af
```

ter picking from autocomplete:

[image]

Instead of `[Object object]` I would like it to be lets say `value.id + value.address` or something similar - in general, custom label for that.

In AngularDart there was an option to specify item redered - a function that takes value and produces "label" for it that is rendered in input field.

Comment: What is that `Host` object? Can you share your component class as well?

Comment: Why does it matter? Its just js object. Sure I can.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an object property called `host` of type `Host`. You are seeing `[object Object]` because you are using the object itself as a value on a text output. Instead of using `host` as the `formControl` in the template, create a new property called `hostField` or something, and assign it a value of `this.host.id + ' ' + this.host.address.toString()`. Can you try that?

Comment: `formControll=host` is as field in `FormGroup` I want that controll to be of `Host` value and display - lets say  - `Host#whatever()` in the input field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always, I knew there is a solution but I forgot what it was as I was reading documentation not carefully enought. What I needed is `[displayWith]` attribute of `MatAutocomplete`. This is exactly  the same thing as item rendered in angular dart components.

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values

Comment: Thanks for this, I read the documentation but missed that part.

Comment: This right here, it's been my resistance to RTFM that held me back.  I appreciate this well-placed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact component class, but here is an example:

```
export class FormFieldObject {
  options: FormGroup;
  value: Host;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.value = {id: 123, address: '555 Some Street'};

    this.options = formBuilder.group({
      color: 'primary',
      val: this.value.id + ' ' + this.value.address.toString(),
    });
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<form class="example-container" [formGroup]="options" [style.fontSize.px]="20">
  <mat-form-field [color]="options.value.color">
    <mat-label>Host</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Host" formControlName="val" min="10">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

This should show `123 555 Some Street` in the field.

Comment: In your example, value of `options->val` is a `string`. I want object (and custom string in DOM).